# Using the Markov property in a proof

Tags: probability

$(\Omega, (F_n), (X_n),\mathbb{P}_x)$ a canonical Markov chain.
$T_x = \inf \{ n \in \mathbb{N}^* ; X_n=x\} $.
$p(x,y)$ is a component of the transition matrix.

In a proof, my textbook say that :
$$
\sum_{x \in E} \sum_{i=1}^\infty E_{x}(1_{\{T_x \geq 1, X_{i-1}=z\}}1_{\{X_i=y\}}) = \sum_{x \in E} \sum_{i=1}^\infty E_{x}(1_{\{T_x \geq 1, X_{i-1}=z\}})p(z,y) 
$$
because of the Markov property (formulate with expectation I guess).

It is probably dumb, but I can't find why this equality is true.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What exactly is $p(z,y)$? You basically want to know why $E_x(... 1_{X_i=y}) = E_x(...)p(z,y)$ right?

Comment: Hello, yes it is what I want to show. $p : E \times E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is the transition matrix.

Comment: That is actually very simple: Ignoring the sums, the left part is the expectation of being in x when $T_x \geq 1$, so there is at least one more step to go, $X_{i-1}=z$, so the $i-1$th step landed in $z$ and $X_i=y$, the $i$ th step landed in $y$.
However, that the $i$ th step landed in $y$ given that $X_{i-1}=z$ has probability $p(z,y)$. Hence the originally wanted expectation is the same as if you only require $T_x\geq 1$ and $X_{i-1}=z$ and then multiply with the last edge probability $p(z,y)$

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It have come to my mind while reading your message. So : $E_x[1_{\{T_x \geq 1 , X_{i-1}=z\}} 1_{\{X_i=y\}}]=E_x[E_x[1_{\{T_x \geq 1 , X_{i-1}=z\}} 1_{\{X_i=y\}} \lvert F_{i-1}]]= E_x[ 1_{\{T_x \geq 1 , X_{i-1}=z\}} E_x[ 1_{\{X_i=y\}} \lvert F_{i-1}]]$.

Comment: And then, with the markov property, $E_x[ 1_{\{T_x \geq 1 , X_{i-1}=z\}} E_x[ 1_{\{X_i=y\}} \lvert F_i]]=E_x[ 1_{\{T_x \geq 1 , X_{i-1}=z\}} E_x[ 1_{\{X_i=y\}} \lvert X_{i-1}]]=E_x[ 1_{\{T_x \geq 1 , X_{i-1}=z\}} P(X_i=y \lvert X_{i-1})]= \sum_{k \in E} 1_{\{T_x \geq 1 , X_{i-1}=z\}}(k) P(X_i=y \lvert X_{i-1}=k) k = P(X_i=y \lvert X_{i-1}=z) z =E_x[ 1_{\{T_x \geq 1 , X_{i-1}=z\}}] P(X_i=y \lvert X_{i-1}=z)=E_x[ 1_{\{T_x \geq 1 , X_{i-1}=z\}}] p(z,y)$.

Comment: Yeah, nice you got it. I'm happy I could help :)